# Addition to make V = { $0, 1,\cdots,2^n-1$} a vector space over $GF(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = { $i \in \mathbb{Z} \mid 0 \leq i < 2^n$} for some positive integer n. How can you define vector addition and scalar multiplication to make this a vector space over $GF(2)$? This problem is from Jonathan Golan's text.

I know that to satisfy $(a+b)v = ab+bv$ and $1 v = v$ it must be true that $v = -v$  for all $v \in V$. However, I can't seem to find a way to get the addition to work. The question says to define both vector addition and scalar multiplication, but I can't see a way to define scalar mult other than $1v = v$ and $0v=0$. I started thinking about $1+1 = 2^k$ where k is some multiple of n, but I can't find a way that doesn't give me more than one inverse.

Comment: Binary expansion of $i$. Then consider $i$ as a vector of its binary digits.

Comment: Your title includes $2^n$, your body does not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

The addition you are looking for is called in computer science **bitwise xor** or bitwise [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), usually denote by the symbol $\oplus$. This extends the exclusive or logical operator to the binary expansion of $i$ and performs it on each decimal place. Can you show that this satisfies the required definitions? As a hint, you can show that this is the same as the usual definition of addition in $GF(2)^n$.